# How can I add multiple validatiors on a field in symfony 1.4

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, field, validation

I have written this code in the 'BaseUserForm' class located in 
`{app}/lib/form/doctrine/base`
 
 **am trying to add two validators to the EMAIL field.**

```
$this->setValidators(array(
        'id' => new sfValidatorChoice(array(
            'choices' => array(
                $this->getObject()->get('id')
            ),
            'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('id'),
            'required' => false
        )),
        'name' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 50)),
        'email' => array(
            new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 100)),
            new sfValidatorEmail(array('trim' => true))
        ),
        'password' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 100)),
        'retyepassword' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 100)),
        'city_id' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array(
            'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Cities')
        )),
        'phone' => new sfValidatorNumber(),
        'created' => new sfValidatorDateTime(),
        'updated' => new sfValidatorDateTime(),
    ));
```

The code above gives error on the defining of two validators for email field.

**Also I am finding it difficult to find out the code related (example showing the usage) of these validators.** The jobeet tutorial is not of much help.

Please share some good blogs/articles/forums wherein i can find help related to the issues discussed above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sfValidatorAnd()` would help;

good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
'email'       => new sfValidatorEmail(array('max_length' => 25, 'required' => TRUE),
                                              array('invalid' => 'The email address is invalid.', 'required' => 'Email Id is required.', 'max_length'=> 'Maximum 25 characters allowed.')),
```